# EF Core SQLite TPH interitance combined key -> duplicate key?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to setup a simple SQLite database using a one-to-many relationship and TPH-mapping.

Table creation has been applied using the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE Masters (Id VARCHAR2 PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Slaves (
    MasterId VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
    Discriminator VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
    SlaveAValue VARCHAR2,
    SlaveBValue VARCHAR2,
    PRIMARY KEY (MasterId, Discriminator),
    FOREIGN KEY (MasterId) REFERENCES Master(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The model classes are defined as:

```
[Table("Masters")]
public class Master
{
    [Column("Id")]
    [Key, Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<Slave> Slaves { get; set; } = new List<Slave>();
}

[Table("Slaves")]
public abstract class Slave
{
    [Column("MasterId")]
    [Required]
    public string MasterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}

public class SlaveA : Slave
{
    [Column("SlaveAValue")]
    [Required]
    public string SlaveAValue { get; set; }
}

public class SlaveB : Slave
{
    [Column("SlaveBValue")]
    [Required]
    public string SlaveBValue { get; set; }
}
```

To tell ef that `slaves` had a combined key I override `OnModelCreating` having the content:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Slave>().HasKey("MasterId", "Discriminator");
base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
```

But if I try to add a value to the context I got an exception:

```
var master = new Master { Id = "Master 01" };
var slaveA = new SlaveA { Master = master, SlaveAValue = "A 01" };
var slaveB = new SlaveB { Master = master, SlaveBValue = "B 01" };

master.Slaves.Add(slaveA);
master.Slaves.Add(slaveB);

await context.Masters.AddAsync(master); // Exception
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The exception message is: `The instance of entity type 'SlaveB' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'MasterId', 'Discriminator'} is already being tracked.`

???

All tables in database are complete empty (new created).

My guess is that the `discriminator` value has not been determined at the point where the master value is added to the context. Adding a field containing the `discriminiator` value will no solve the problem (I also guessed that but gave it a try...).

Do I realy have to add a dedicated id-column to the slave table to make it work with ef-core or is there any other solution?

**Solution based on a hint of SBFrancies**

Add a field to the base class `Slave` called `Discriminator`:

```
[Column("Discriminator")]
[Required]
public abstract string Discriminator { get; set; }
```

Change the implementation of `SlaveA` and `SlaveB`:

```
public override string Discriminator
{
    get => nameof(SlaveA); 
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two slaves have the same MasterID  ("Master 01") and the same Discriminator (null) so they have the same primary key which is causing the problem.

**Update**

A possible solution is to add a Discriminator for each type:

```
public class SlaveA : Slave
{
    public string Discriminator => "S1";

    [Column("SlaveAValue")]
    [Required]
    public string SlaveAValue { get; set; }
}

public class SlaveB : Slave
{
    public string Discriminator => "S2";

    [Column("SlaveBValue")]
    [Required]
    public string SlaveBValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Alternative solution**

Apologies for the above. I think a better option is to have a new artificial primary key on the Slaves table.

```
CREATE TABLE Slaves (
    SlavesId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    MasterId VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
    Discriminator VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
    SlaveAValue VARCHAR2,
    SlaveBValue VARCHAR2,
    FOREIGN KEY (MasterId) REFERENCES Master(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

[Table("Slaves")]
public abstract class Slave
{

    [Column("SlaveId")]
    [Key]
    public int SlaveId {get;set;}

    [Column("MasterId")]
    [Required]
    public string MasterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a unique index in your database to ensure you do not have more than one type per master:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX master_index ON Slaves(MasterId, Discriminator);
```

Comment: This was my guess - but how to solve that problem? I don't have a `Discriminator` value in the model classes - and I don't want any.

Comment: I've added a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it but at context creation I got the error `'No backing field could be found for property 'Discriminator' of entity type 'Slave' and the property does not have a setter.'`. I tried to add an abstract property to the base class. If I don't add it to the base class I get an error at the `HasKey`-clause because this class doesn't contain a property called `Discriminator`.
I implemented it like `public override string Discriminator { get => nameof(SlaveA); set { } }` and an abstract property `Discriminator` in `Slave`. This works. But TPH forces this column but couldn't hande it?

Comment: Please revert the outlining of your code. That was the hint that forces me to the solution.

Comment: Have done and I've added a different solution. Glad you go it to work.

Comment: You won't believe it but your alternative solution including the unqiue combined index was exactly the solution that I implemented as solution. But it doesn't match as answer to my question and thats why I don't wrote it into the question.